# Using static classes in Business Logic Layer

Tags: design-patterns, static, business-logic, n-tier-architecture

I am aware that the answer to my question might involve choosing a specific approach, But I try to explain what I'm trying to find out with details:

Consider a simple 3-layer application (DAL, BLL, PL).
DAL uses EF 4.1 Code-First and access to data is wrapped up in a reposiory.

Right now, in BLL, I have `Manager` classes. (e.g. `UserManager`, `ProductManager`) which all derive from `BaseManager`. Almost each method in my Manager classes take their related entity as a parameter and perform the appropriate operations on it. e.g. in `UserManager` (Pseudo code):

```
public bool AddPermission(User user, PermissionItem permission)
{
    this.repository.Add(permission);
    this.save();
}
```

Question is: My manager classes do not need to get instantiated. they can be defined static.
But if I define them static, I should create my shared methods and members (like `repository`, and a couple of other members) in each class (I do not want to define members like repository as static).

So do you suggest I should change my Manager classes that are indeed meant to be static to static classes? or is it ok using them as they are?

Comment: what is repository? I've been conditioned at work to make all business objects stateless because our system is multi-user and if we make it stateless than we can just create 1 instance of our business objects that all users can share without messing with each other's data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imho static classes are nothing more than containers for functions (and not real objects). The difference is that non-static classes can be derived and get their dependencies through the constructor.

Try to write proper tests for a static class.

You might not have intended for them to be instances today, but what about tomorrow? If you change them to static, you'll have to refactor all your depending code to unmake them static.

I would rather start using an inversion of control container to manage their creation and instances.

Comment: Using IoC to control my managers' creation is the path I'll most probably choose.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to make them static. As far as I can see, it would only complicate the API and the implementation. And where would your callers retrieve the repository from? Should they look it up for each call? That's wasteful. Far better to look it up once and store it within the manager. That's what instance variables are for.

Answer (score 0):

I like to create a static "directory" (the correct name for this object is actually repository) that contains all my instances.  For example:

```
public static Class BusinessRepository
{
    private static Users users = new Users();

    public static Users Users
    {
        get
        {
            return users;
        }
    }
}
```

The BusinessRepository class is static, but Users is an instance object contained within it.  This can then be accessed like this:

```
BusinessRepository.Users.DoSomething();
```

This way you get to keep your object instances and all the benefits that they bring, with static like access to them.

A lot of people dont agree with these sort of "global variables" as they will call them, but that is your judgement call to make.  It seems like you've already made the decision that you're happy with this as you're already talking about static classes.